# can you please help me in asp.net registration page creation

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'C:\USERS\REGE\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2013\WEBSITES\LOGINPAGE1\APP_DATA\REGISTRATION.MDF.dbo.UserData'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at Registration.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\rege\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\Loginpage1\Registration.aspx.cs:line 39 ClientConnectionId:53472e69-8d36-4409-b2bc-92fd8344be27
UserName
Email
Password
Confirm Password
Country

please somebody help me what is the problem in the program coz i am now a programmer
thanks

Comment: That is a pretty explicit error.  You are apparently trying to insert NULL into the Id column, which does not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the exception said you did not include ***value for Id column*** when you insert a record.

If ***Id Data Type***  is ***int***, it might be that you forget to set it as ***[Identity Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)***.

[image]